# How to re-use the same function but call it from different locations in python in same test script

Tags: python, function, generator, reusability

I've a test case in which I've to "End the process" from different screens on a device and I've a function to emulate the different screens.
After EndProcess(), device returns to screen1(). Any optimistic way to do this in Python? Can I use a generator here?

Currently, my code is:

```
while 1:
    screen1()
    EndProcess()
    screen1()
    screen2()
    EndProcess()
    screen1()
    screen2()
    screen3()
    EndProcess()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be repeating yourself so many times when the number of screens become relatively large. Instead, you can put the screens in a list and call them using a *for* loop:

```
screens = [screen1, screen2, screen3]

while True:
   for x in range(len(screens)):
      for i in range(x+1):
         screens[i]()
      EndProcess()
```

Use `xrange` in place of `range` in Python 2.